# How to split array in javascript for d3

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to split array something like this:

```
input: [a,b,c,d,e];

output: [[a,b], [b,c], [c,d], [d,e]];
```

Comment: tried anything?

Comment: Nope!!! Confused @Dinesh

Comment: @HussainDehgamwala I am sure that you can find something to try.. Stat with a loop..

Comment: Step 1: think about your problem, figure out what logical process would turn your input into your desired output. Step 2: think about what code you can write that will accomplish this and then write this code. Step 3: if your code doesn't work the way you intended and you can't see why, then post a question on Stackoverflow and **include your attempted code in the question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
var input = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += 1) {
        output[i] = [];
    output[i].push(input[i]);
    output[i].push(input[i + 1]);
}
```